# Align_parent programmatically reset

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I have a problem with reset align_parent. The idea is that we have an object in the window and we can control it with buttons, but I have a problem with the fact that if I press setTop, it will reach the indicated position, but then when I press setBottom, the button is in place. I have the impression that the variable reset is not working properly but I don't understand why. Maybe you know if he is typing removeRule incorrectly or is there any other way to set the align_parent and center_horizontal values to false?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_margins_train)

        val testbox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testbox)
        val setTop = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.setTop)
        val setBottom = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.setBottom)
        val parameters = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(heightBox.toInt(),widthBox.toInt())

        val reset = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(heightBox.toInt(),widthBox.toInt())
        .apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END) }.apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP) }
        .apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM) }.apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START) }
        .apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) }.apply { removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL) }

        setTop.setOnClickListener {
            testbox.layoutParams = reset
            testbox.layoutParams = parameters.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) }.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP) }
        }
        setBottom.setOnClickListener {
            testbox.layoutParams = reset
            testbox.layoutParams = parameters.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) }.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM) } }
        }
```

XML code

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MarginsTrain">

    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/setTop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/testing"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder_box"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/setBottom"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/testing"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder_box"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
    
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/testing"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@color/teal_200">
    
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/testbox"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/testboxWidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/testboxHeight"
                        android:background="@color/purple_500"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/RelativeLayoutTestTextBox"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share your  `activity_margins_train` layout?

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
testbox.layoutParams = reset
```

has no effect since it is immediately followed by

```
testbox.layoutParams = parameters.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) }.apply { addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM) } }
```

and is therefore overridden before a layout can occur. Maybe the following statement will help correct the problem:

```
testbox.layoutParams = reset.apply { 
    addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM) } }
```

I would take a closer look at this area. I am also curious why there are so many chained `.apply{}` when one would do.